# equivalent of .net output cache in node.js?

Tags: node.js, memcached, redis, express, http-caching

New to node coming over from asp.net so was curious about the best modules/frameworks to implement caching in node.js.  I would like to cache some expensive db queries so looking for an easy way to cache db results or entire http page output to memory.

In .net it would be using either httpcache or page output caching.  Is there an equivalent in the node world?

Should I just set up a local memcached or redis server to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using express then there is a [settings](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#settings) option for enabling view cache, also since express is built on top of connect you can try to look at [connect-cache](https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-cache) module. For caching static stuff you can take a look at [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) for example. Caching database queries in memcached or redis may be highly dependent on your data structure, but I would probably choose redis since it supports [more advanced data structures](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) which may be handy.